# What does this line in the Lua language do?

Tags: lua

What does this line in the Lua language do?

```
module(..., package.seeall)
```

As far as I understand she tries to load other bibiliotek in the project. If this is so, in what place the C files written by me which expand standard opportunities of Lua of language, i.e. additional functions lie.

Comment: What version of Lua is this?

Comment: I have lua version 5.2

Comment: `to podgruzit other bibiliotek in the project` :). No this is for create pure Lua module. Not load existed one. To load usially use `require` function. `module` is depricated in 5.2.

Comment: The down vote is a bit unfair... Unfortunately Google translate doesn't know `podgruzit`...

Answer (score 0):

The [`module()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-module) function is used to define Lua modules in Lua 5.1. Its main visible effect is that all assignments to global variables (in particular global function definitions) end up in the module table and not in the globals table. It does so by replacing the current environment. Unfortunately, this means that all read accesses to global variables are also redirected to the module table, so unless you create local aliases before the `module()` call, you'd lose access to those global variables. The [`package.seeall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.seeall) argument mitigates this flaw by setting a metatable on the module table, and thus allowing you to access global variables via the module table. The first argument to `module()` is just the module name, and `...` holds the name that was requested via the [`require()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) call (a "feature" of `module()` is that you can define a module different from the one that is requested). Anyway, `module()` is deprecated in Lua 5.2, and unavailable by default in Lua 5.3. See [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued) for reasons why.